# Microsoft Visual Foxpro OleDb provider error: System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: 'Feature is not available.'

Tags: visual-foxpro, dbf

In the same folder I have two files: company.dbf and company.cdx.
My code fragment:

```
OleDbConnection oleDbCon = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=VFPOLEDB.1; Data Source=c:\DBF\; Collating Sequence=MACHINE");
string rows = @"SELECT name FROM [company.dbf]";
OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(rows, oleDbCon);
```

Running code I have error: **System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: 'Feature is not available.'**

If I delete or rename index file (company.cdx), app works as should. Seems provider tries to open index file instead of dbf. What I do wrong?

Another question: Where to find all Visual Foxpro Oledb provider connection string parameters?

Comment: I think there is one or more tags in the cdx (index) file with keys having expressions that contain unsupported functions in it. Did you try documenting the indexes at all?

Comment: Connection string parameters are available in help. But in general it is as simple as: @"Provider=VFPOLEDB;Data Source=c:\DBF". You may also want to check in www.connectionstrings.com

Comment: Structural index files are always opened and updated along with their data file. You still didn't share index key expressions.

Comment: The question is not about using index files - I do not it at all. We have application, created using Visual FoxPro. This application uses index files. U just want to create an other application to copy data from dbf file to Mysql database. So, I do not need indexes, but I can not delete this files from current folder. The question is "Why connection string + sql query select try to open cdx file instead of dbf?"

Comment: Unfortunately, I did find detailed information about connection string parameters. Could you provide link for that?

Comment: What you don't understand is, whenever there is a structural index file, it is opened by default when you attempt to open the dbf itself. It not only opens it, it uses it when you query the table. If an index expression (which might call functions) contains some unsupported feature, then you would get that error. In your query actually it is just select * from [company]. Specifying extension is not necessary and it would open all related files (cdx, fpt if any) regardless of you want to only open the dbf itself.

Comment: What do you need about the connection string parameters? You can check VFP help file, OLEDB 2.5 reference guide and connectionstrings.com but as I said earlier it is as simple as provider name and data source.

Comment: Well, it's clear for me now about index files, thanks a lot.